# Mono GC SGen collecting too slowly

Tags: c#, mono, garbage-collection

I am using mono 3.2.8 and the default SGen to collect memory. I log every 10 mins the memory usage of my .NET 4.0 application and came to the following conclusion:

Memory is rising slowly till nearly no more free system memory is left (like 4MB). When it comes to this point, a big amount (like 10-20 MB) is collected at once.

Is there a way to control the frequency of the collection (more often), withought collecting it manually?

What could be the reason for this behaviour (in code and in GC)?

Thx for your help!

Comment: 3.2.8 is years older than the latest. Did you test also against 4.0?

Comment: 3.2.8 mono was released in Feb. 2014, not that old imao. Yes I compiled against 4.0 .NET.

Comment: No, but I dont want to use it anyway because its the latest stable version of mono in Debian (jessie) where I am running mono.